# Как сделать чтобы Chrome через Selenium при старте становился активным окном?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

Делаю все это через питон на маке. При этом запущен хром с другим профайлом. Как сделать чтобы новый хром через селениум сразу становился бы активным окном?

Answer (score 2):

- Непонятно какой именно селениум имеется ввиду. Веб драйвер или же первый.
- Непонятно какой язык используется.

Ну да ладно. 
Хочешь -- дам ответ на шарп. Соответственно реализовать его возможно только на веб-драйвере.

```
static void BringWindowToFront()
{
    var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("имяПроцессаХрома");
    var process = processes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id!=currentProcess.Id);
    if (process == null) return;

    SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Сам виноват что не пишешь детали.
Но на сам твой вопрос ответ более чем коректный